# Why does PyTorch gather function require index argument to be of type LongTensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm writing some code in PyTorch and I came across the gather function. Checking the documentation I saw that the index argument takes in a LongTensor, why is that? Why does it need to take in a LongTensor instead of another type such as IntTensor? What are the benefits?

Comment: Long is a datatype that can hold decimal values but not int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all indices in pytorch are represented as long tensors - allowing for indexing very large tensors beyond just 4GB elements (maximal value of "regular" int).